# Using re and matching, how can I search and get certain data from a text file?

Tags: python, matching, python-re

I have used re and matching to extract certain data from a text file.
But I have issues trying to get specific data using similar technique. Keep getting stuck. So posting the code I used to get the lines I require.
Details are at the end of the code below.
Thank you in advance!

Data from text file:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
  SU MO TU WE TH FR SA SU MO TU WE TH FR SA SU MO TU WE TH FR SA SU MO TU WE TH FR SA SU MO TU WE TH FR SA SU MO
 121               192                  175               158                  168                              BLK NO.  101 DYS OFF  17
 CVGORD X  X  X  X AVPDSMORD X  X  X  X GRBDSMORD X  X  X PIALEXORD X  X  X  X CHALEXORD X  X                   CRD.   72.00 BLK.  58.31
  121= 0910/1255/0901; 192= 0810/1915/1536; 175= 0750/1218/0931; 158= 0730/1240/1359; 168= 0758/1239/1638;      TAFB  245.09 C/O    0.0
```

Code: **sorry forgot to add myDict[key] from my code** EDITED

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        matchObj = re.match(dashes1, line)
        if matchObj:
            count += 1
            strcount =str(count)
            data = ['','','','']
            f.readline()
            f.readline()
            data[0] = f.readline()
            data[1] = f.readline()
            key = "myData"+strcount
            myDict[key] = data
f.close()   



for key in myDict:
    print(key, '->', myDict[key])
```

My output is:

```
myData1 -> [' 121               192                  175               158                  168                              BLK NO.  101 DYS OFF  17\n', ' CVGORD X  X  X  X AVPDSMORD X  X  X  X GRBDSMORD X  X  X PIALEXORD X  X  X  X CHALEXORD X  X                   CRD.   72.00 BLK.  58.31\n', '', '']
```

I want to get the data after BLK NO. that is 101, data after DYS OFF which is 17, and so on for CRD. value of 72.00 and BLK. value of 58.31.

I don't want to print BLK NO., DYS OFF, CRD. nor BLK. just the values after them.
I have tried the same method using re and matching but I get stuck.
Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: You don't need `f.close()`, `with` automatically closes the file at the end.

Comment: You never add anything to `myDict`.

Comment: You could do something like `line.partition('BLK NO.')[2].partition('DYS OFF')[0].strip()`

Answer (score 1):

I would keep things sane and simple, and just use `re.findall` here, after reading the entire content into a string:

```py
inp = """-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
SU MO TU WE TH FR SA SU MO TU WE TH FR SA SU MO TU WE TH FR SA SU MO TU WE TH FR SA SU MO TU WE TH FR SA SU MO
121               192                  175               158                  168                              BLK NO.  101 DYS OFF  17
CVGORD X  X  X  X AVPDSMORD X  X  X  X GRBDSMORD X  X  X PIALEXORD X  X  X  X CHALEXORD X  X                   CRD.   72.00 BLK.  58.31
121= 0910/1255/0901; 192= 0810/1915/1536; 175= 0750/1218/0931; 158= 0730/1240/1359; 168= 0758/1239/1638;      TAFB  245.09 C/O    0.0"""

keys = ["BLK NO\.", "DYS OFF", "CRD\.", "BLK\.", "TAFB", "C/O"]
regex = "(" + "|".join(keys) + ")"
matches = re.findall(regex + r'\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
[('BLK NO.', '101'), ('DYS OFF', '17'), ('CRD.', '72.00'), ('BLK.', '58.31'),
 ('TAFB', '245.09'), ('C/O', '0.0')]
```

Comment: Nice use of keys, never encountered it before

Comment: But the text file is rather huge, so I can't really import entire content into a string... or can I ? How can I incorporate the test.txt file into this code?

Comment: @AAAlex123 Now you have the keys, go get driving `:-)`

Comment: @Damian Define "rather huge."  A few MB should be no problem for the Python interpreter.  If your file really is what I would consider massive (e.g. GBs), then you could still try reading it in chunks and use my solution above.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen haha ok gotcha, no it is approximately 1-2 MB. Thank you!  For importing would using  importlib  simply work?

Comment: @Damian Are you waiting for a different/better answer?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I need to extract ONLY the values, not other strings. And importing text file using open(myfile, 'r').readlines() and running that did not work.

Comment: ...if you don't also extract the keys, then how do you know to which keys the values would correspond (unless your text would always be fixed)?  If you just want values, then make the keys non capturing.  You will only get values back.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry but I am confused as to how to do this. The file has lots of this type of data, and I am sorting it to only extract the values for me, in table form - columns of each. I will use tabulate for this, but need only the values.

Comment: I have answered the question you actually asked, using the data you actually gave.  If you have some other requirement, maybe you need to rethink things.

Comment: Yes and no. I wrote at the bottom that I want to extrapolate ONLY the values, nothing else. You did help, got me closer to finding an answer, thank you; but still haven't answered it based on that question.